# Matrix 2-norm of a column vector and its tranpose

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $a$ be a $n\times 1$ column vector. Then, $aa^{T}$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix.

For a few examples, I've noticed in Octave that $aa^{T}$ has a single nonzero eigenvalue which appears to be equal to $\|a\|_{2}^{2}$. Is there a way to formalize this?

I know that $\|A\|_{2} = \sqrt{\rho(A^{T}A)}$, i.e. the spectral radius of $A^{T}A$. Is there a connection here for the column vector?

Comment: It is not hard to prove that $aa^T$ is symmetric non-negative matrix, and since $rang(a) = rang(a^T) = 1$, hence $rang(aa^T) = 1$. Since we know that  $aa^T$ is symmetric non-negative matrix of rang 1, therefore there is one and only one strictly positive eigenvalue, and others are zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a a^t v$ for several values of $v$.

1. $v = a$. The result is $a (a^t a) = a \| a\|^2$.
2. $a \cdot v = 0$. The result is $a (a^t v) = a (a \cdot v) = 0$.

Since there is a basis consisting of $a$ and then $n-1$ more vectors that are orthogonal to $a$, we see that $a a^t$ has one eigenvalue $\| a \|^2$ and $n-1$ zero eigenvalues.

[This is simply an explicit working out of what @Hello said in the comments]